# Laravel Vercel + Postgre Supabase

Tags: postgresql, vercel, supabase, laravel-10

when I use supabase on local and I try 'php artisan migrate' it works but when I try on production I get the error 'could find driver pgsql'

I have tried the terminal on my Laravel Vercel and config: clear but it still doesn't work